# Phaser Tween.onStart works only 1 time?

Tags: tween, phaser-framework

I've created some buttons for the main menu of my game and I wanted to add a nice animation of the buttons moving off screen with a short delay after each other.

So I made a bunch of buttons and gave each of them their own tween and then combined the tweening process like this:

```
tempTweens[0].onStart.add(function () {
    console.log('onStart fired'); 
    game.time.events.add(tweenDelay, function () {
        tempTweens[1].start();
    }, this);

    game.time.events.add(tweenDelay * 2, function () {
        tempTweens[2].start();
    }, this);

    game.time.events.add(tweenDelay * 3, function () {
        tempTweens[3].start();
    }, this);
}, this);
```

But when I do tempTweens[0].start(); it does what I want it to.... 1 time. The second time I do tempTweens[0].start(); it only moves the first button and not the other ones.

I even made a small loop after this code to check.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tempTweens[0].start();
    }
```

and it only writes 'onStart fired' to console 1 time.

Any idea how I can make .onStart work every time I start this first tween?

I'm thinking I haven't fully understood how .onStart works but my guess was that stuff like this should only happen if I had used .addOnce not .add.

Answer (score 0):

Update.

I did get the desired effect by creating a separate function, just now.

```
function animateMainMenuButtons(tweens) {
var tweenDelay = 50;

tweens[0].start();
game.time.events.add(tweenDelay, function () {
    tweens[1].start();
}, this);
game.time.events.add(tweenDelay * 2, function () {
    tweens[2].start();
}, this);
game.time.events.add(tweenDelay * 3, function () {
    tweens[3].start();
}, this); }
```

But I'd still like any input about the original post, since it seems I am lacking some sort of info on how .onStart works and when it's actually fired. This most likely will come back to haunt me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Phaser tweens are not meant to be re-used. You need to create the tween every time you need to use it. I faced the same problem and try to hack it with some success by doing `tween._hasStarted = false` and `tweeen.pendingDelete = false`. But i advise you to not do this.

Comment: Wan't expecting to get a reply after such a long time. Already working on different projects. But I would gladly accept your answer to close off this question, if you provided a credible source that tweens indeed are only meant to be used once.

Comment: Yeah, this answer needs a source, I can't find anything about not reusing Tweens. This did, however, solve my issue. But adding a new tween each time feels a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

## For simple Tween management add an object of tweens to call

You can `add` a new tween on each call. This means that the `data` attribute is fresh each time.

This was my approach inside a class that extends a game object (Image, Sprite .etc)

```js
initTweens = () => {
    this.tweens = {
        scaleUp: () => this.scene.tweens.add({
            targets: this,
            scale: 2.4,
            duration: 100,
            ease: 'Circ',
        }),
        scaleDown: () => this.scene.tweens.add({
            targets: this,
            scale: 2,
            duration: 100,
            ease: 'Circ',
        }),
        playCard: () => this.scene.tweens.add({
            targets: this,
            x: this.scene.PlayMat.playMat.x,
            y: this.scene.PlayMat.playMat.y,
            duration: 300,
            ease: 'Circ',
        }),
        resetCard: () => this.scene.tweens.add({
            targets: this,
            x: this.initialX,
            y: this.initialY,
            duration: 300,
            ease: 'Circ',
            onStart: (ween, git) => {
                console.log('started reset');
            },
            onComplete: (ween, git) => {
                console.log('complete reset');
            },
        })
    }
}
```

Make sure you init this function in the constructor or create methods after setting up your class attributes

```js
constructor(scene: Game, x, y, texture, id) {
        super(scene, x, y, texture);
        this.id = id;
        this.scene = scene;
        this.initialX = x;
        this.initialY = y;
        this.scale = 2
        this.setInteractive({ draggable: true });
        scene.physics.world.enable(this);
        this.initTweens() // this line
```

Finally you can trigger a tween by just calling the object and firing the function. Like so.

```js
this.tweens.playCard();
// or
this.tweens.resetCard();
```

## Conclusion

This will now trigger both the `onStart` and `onComplete` tween methods each time you call them

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but for those, who still interested, I think you can use Phaser's 3 tween timeline in order to play tweens in a sequence. Read more [here](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/tween-timeline/) and see example [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tweens/timelines/create-timeline).

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning Phaser right now and also encountered the issue of not being able to repeat tween chains multiple times. I stumbled upon this thread to learn it wasn't super simple.

However after some trouble shooting I learned I was able to repeat my animations by simply doing `tweens.restart()` before I did `tweens.play()`.

Maybe I'm reading the code in this thread wrong, but I think its possible you could do the same thing here.